# zypper not working in a fresh opensuse/tumbleweed container

Tags: docker, opensuse

Since the last update yesterday, I can't run zypper in a fresh opensuse/tumbleweed docker container...

ref: https://hub.docker.com/r/opensuse/tumbleweed

### Observed

```sh
$ docker rmi opensuse/tumbleweed
$ docker run --rm --init -it opensuse/tumbleweed bash -c "zypper update"
Unable to find image 'opensuse/tumbleweed:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from opensuse/tumbleweed
9fdd7ffbcda9: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:ba4b07a94d177ce2ac02bbd4b76eefdffd85681a0a231ca8bcada52e1d7feab0
Status: Downloaded newer image for opensuse/tumbleweed:latest
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Operation not permitted
```

### Expected

just work like before not having this:
`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'`

### Note

- Already asked on irc.libera.chat without success
- `docker run --rm --init -it opensuse/leap bash -c "zypper update"` is working as expected...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a new major issue.

Seems to be tracked by https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1190670
see: https://openqa.opensuse.org/tests/1926064#step/docker_image/182